# DateTime picker: Disable time later than current hour in current day and enable time for previous days

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, datetimepicker

I have a DateTime Picker i want to limit errors in users input so i'm diabling any input for future dates and times. i want to disable times later than the current hour of the current day .At the same time, if the user wants to add an old day , all the times would be active and can select anytime from them.

```
<div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Start_Time, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Start_Time, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", ID = "StartTime" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Start_Time, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.End_Time, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.End_Time, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.End_Time, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('input[type=datetime]').datetimepicker({
                dateFormat: "dd/M/yy",
                changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true,
                yearRange: "-60:+0",
                maxDate:0
                
            });
        });
    </script>
```

i tried writing this function but the datetimepicker stopped popping so it's not working

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
            var theDay = new Date;
            var theStartDate = $('#StartTime').value();
            if (theStartDate === new Date) {
                $('input[type=datetime]').datetimepicker({
                    dateFormat: "dd/M/yy",
                    changeMonth: true,
                    changeYear: true,
                    yearRange: "-60:+0",
                    maxDate: 0,
                    maxTime: 0
                });
            }
            else if (theStartDate < new Date) {
                $('input[type=datetime]').datetimepicker({
                    dateFormat: "dd/M/yy",
                    changeMonth: true,
                    changeYear: true,
                    yearRange: "-60:+0",
                    maxDate: theDay

                });

            }
        });
```

Comment: Can you mention the library link?

Comment: Also in a simple word you have two date time pickers e.g one start & another end & you want if user selects start then the end time will be after start & if end is selected then start will be before end also default value of end is today right?

Comment: no , In the Start time for example,if the user selects 6-9-2020 12pm then the user can't select time later than 12.but if the user select an old date like 31-8-2020 the times will be active and can select any time from it.

Comment: this is the documentation written at the top of the script page :    /**
 * preserve jQuery DateTimePicker plugin v2.4.5
 * homepage http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/
 * (c) 2014, Chupurnov Valeriy.
 */